# <jsp:root and <html xmlns

Tags: eclipse, html, jsp, jstl

In a JSP, do I need to provide a `jsp:root` directive *and* an XML namespace declaration. Or only the later. That is, if I have the following:

```
 <jsp:directive.page language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
 />
 <jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
 />
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
 <head>
      ... remainder of my HTML page
```

should I remove the `jsp:root` element? The information seems redundant. Removing the namespace declaration from the `html` element makes Eclipse complain.

Answer (score 0):

You need the jsp:root element to set up the rest of the document to understand tags beginning with s: or c:. So don't remove it.